# How to include boostrap 4 into custom wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm working on custom wordpress theme and i try to include custom html content into my page with boostrap 4 code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have add localy all boostrap dependencies into my theme according to [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/) :

```
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'boostrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/boostrap.min.css' );

    /* Boostrap 4 library */
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-theme',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js', array(), '3.2.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('popper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.min.js', array(), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery', 'popper'), '4.0.0', true );
}
```

When i go on my webpage, i see all columns into different line :(

[image]

How can i include boostrap into my wordpress theme ? Is there any special operation ?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check your filename, because your loading a file called **boostrap.min.css**

`wp_enqueue_style( 'boostrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/boostrap.min.css' );`

Comment: Oupss. I'm ashamed :(
Thanks for your response !

Comment: No problem, we've all been there before...trust me!